# Get length of child elements inside body main element Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

How Do I get the length of all the elements inside this particular BODY?

`XPATH = //*[@id="createEdit"]/div/div/table/tbody`

```
<tbody data-v-97081d06="">
    <tr data-v-97081d06="" gogo-test="data_table_with_selection_row_0" tabindex="0" class="t-body--sansSerif">
    <tr data-v-97081d06="" gogo-test="data_table_with_selection_row_1" tabindex="0" class="t-body--sansSerif">
    <tr data-v-97081d06="" gogo-test="data_table_with_selection_row_2" tabindex="0" class="t-body--sansSerif">
</tbody>
```

There is a total of 3 elements inside it and I want to get the length of it from the main element.

Comment: What length in this case should mean? Do you mean you want to count `tr` nodes?

Comment: Yes, Length of total elements inside the body, In this case, there are 3 with tr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count child elements you can do

```
tbody = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="createEdit"]/div/div/table/tbody')
print(len(tbody.find_elements_by_xpath('./*')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, instead of getting the length of all the elements inside the `<body>` tag you may like to get the length of all the `<tr>` elements within the `<body>`.

To get the length of the `<tr>` elements you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#createEdit > div > div > table > tbody tr")))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="createEdit"]/div/div/table/tbody//tr")))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#createEdit > div > div > table > tbody tr")))))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="createEdit"]/div/div/table/tbody//tr")))))
  ```